# Connecting SATA Hard Disk drive as a slave/seconda disk to a PC?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have a motherboard with only two SATA ports. I am using both, one for a HDD and one to a CDROM/DVD.

I want to connect a second SATA hard disk drive(HDD), but as stated the mother board I have does not have an extra SATA connector.

So I just unplugged the CDROM/DVD SATA connector and power connector and used them to connect this second SATA HDD to the existing system.

Question: Is this correct way of connecting a second SATA disk as slave?

The PC did booted up(Windows-7 x64) but could not show me the second disk as a drive?

Question 2: If everything else is fine, should this drive be detected?

Comment: Depends, is the drive formatted? check administrative tools>computer management> disk management and see if it shows up there.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is the way to go. You can connect only one device per channel

It is strange you have only 2 SATA ports on the motherboard - maybe very old one

Comment: @What i meant was there are 4 SATA ports on the motherboard, but only 2 cables from two of those - 1 to primary HDD, 2nd to CDROM/DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it all in the BIOS. The BIOS controls boot order for SATA: it's actually really nice compared to the horrible jumpers. You just tell it which SATA device is the boot device, and you're done. Very simple.

As for why it's not showing up, SATA is a little picky, so it's probably not picking up the new drive because the type is set incorrectly. Some DVD drives need to have IDE emulation set, even though they have SATA connectors. If that was done, it would cause this sort of issue. Again, this is set in the BIOS. You can probably just switch it to "AUTO".

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange because in SATA it is just plug and play thing. since both the HDDS are not sharing channels it should not give you problems, and as you explained you did your connections well. please do not get tired and redo your connections again may be something is loose some where,still enter Bios and set the booting order the HDD having OS being number one.